Largest $3$-connected graphs containing no subdivisions of $K_{3,3}$
I saw a problem in the book Combinatorial Problems and Exercise written by Lovasz.
Section 10, 5(b):
Every simple $3$-connected graph with $n\ge 6$ vertices and $3n-5$ edges contains a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$.
It is not hard to solve the above exercise. But I want to construct a $3$-connected graph with $3n-6$ edges containing no subdivisions of $K_{3,3}$.
Here is my attempt on the base case $n=6$: Let $1234561$ be a $6$-cycle, then add the edges $13,24,35,46,51,62$. This graph has $12$ edges and contains no subdivisions of $K_{3,3}$.
I failed to extend this construction for general $n$. I wonder if someone could help me.

Any plane triangulation will work: they all have $3n - 6$ edges, are 3-connected and do not contain $K_{3,3}$ subdivisions by Kuratowski's Theorem.
You can do this really naively too - put down $n$ vertices arranged randomly and keep connecting them until every region is a triangle.
